# Iterar sobre un array de forma recursiva en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

Hola a todos compañeros estoy tratando de aprender la recursividad, el concepto lo tengo claro y lo entiendo , el problema es saber como aplicar la recursividad. Estoy tratando de recorrer un array de numero como este [1,2,3,4,5] de forma recursiva y obtener su producto es decir multiplicar sus numero por ejemplo `1*2*3*4*5` pero no me sale alguien me podría ayudar.
El ejercicio mas exactamente es el siguiente:

```
const producto = function(array){
}
producto([1,2,5]);
```

lo que he intentado hacer sin éxito era lo siguiente:

```
const producto = function(array){
    if(array.length == 1){
        return array;
    }else{
    return array[0] * producto(array.slice(1,0));
    }
}

producto([1,2,5])
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a stackoverflow, te recomendaria editar tu pregunta y colocar aquello que haz intentado sin exito en codigo, asi sea muy poco, es muy importante proveernos de un ejemplo minimo y verificable, tambien recordar que las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas en stackoverflow, se que tu pregunta no es basada en opiniones, pero trata de evitar este tipo de pregunta a futuros, tambien como eres un nuevo usuario te invito a pasear por el [tour] y leer [ask], para que puedas entender de mejor manera el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Hola si claro les pido una disculpa a todos, para las próximas preguntas tendré todo el reglamento en cuenta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para la recursividad siempre necesitas un caso base que detenga las llamadas recursivas y resuelva todas las llamadas.

Quieres multiplicar cada uno de los números en un arreglo, por tanto, necesitas un parámetro con el cual recorrerlo al que llamaremos `i`. Este parámetro marcará el caso base cuando la `i` sea igual a la longitud del arreglo. Nota que este parámetro es necesario con el objetivo de **NO MODIFICAR** el arreglo original y que no es necesario especificarlo para invocar la función ya que tiene un valor predefinido.

```js
function producto(array, i=0) {
  if(array.length == i){
     return 1;
  }
  return array[i] * producto(array, i + 1);
}

console.log(producto([5,2,3]))
```

Si no te importa modificar el array original (lo cual no es muy recomendado), puedes ir extrayendo elementos hasta vaciar el arreglo. El caso base en este caso sería cuando la longitud del arreglo sea 0. En este caso, no necesitas un parámetro auxiliar.

```js
function producto(array) {
  if(array.length == 0){
     return 1;
  }
  return array.pop() * producto(array);
}

console.log(producto([5,2,3]))
```

Comment: A la persona que ha votado negativo, le agradecería que pusiera sus argumentos y sus razones. Un voto 3 segundos después de publicada la respuesta sin razón alguna.

Comment: Fui yo, pero las razones son para beneficio del usuario, recuerda que segun los lineamientos de la comunidad es mejor no proveer una respuesta sin que el usuario nos haya proveido de primero un ejemplo minimo de aquello que ha intentado pero sin exito, al inicio tambien era de los que respondia directamente aunque no pusieran codigo, es decir, decia... es un usuario nuevo no sabe como hacerlo, pero ten en cuenta que... mas que ayudar al usuario en este caso si no le das la oportunidad de primero pensar por si mismo el no va a aprender, por este motivo mi voto negativo.

Comment: Debes darle un espacio al `OP` para que pueda aprender y no mal acostumbrarlo a respuestas sin un contexto detras, creeme que ya me ha pasado con otras preguntas, y si, al incio parece injusto, pero luego cobra sentido, que gana el `OP` con que le faciliten todo sin tener que trabajar en el codigo?, yo fui el primero que voto, pero estoy seguro de que si no hubiese sido el primero ya lo hubiese hecho alguien mas xd,  ya me conozco la comunidad.

Comment: La recursividad no es un concepto fácil de aplicar, y es totalmente comprensible que alguien que empieza no sepa como afrontar un primer acercamiento a la iteración de esta forma. Preguntas peores se han respondido acá y esta me parece clara y concisa. Pero respeto tu opinión y tu voto, aunque no creo que haya estado bien tomarla con mi respuesta cuando ya votaste negativo por la pregunta. De cualquier manera te agradezco que hayas dado la cara.

Answer (score 1):

El siguiente código puedes probarlo usando node, la función foo, es recursiva:
Mientras el índice i sea menor que la posición del último elemento, regresa recursivamente el producto, y cuando esa condición se rompe, devulve nada más el valor del último elemento

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];

function foo(arr,i){
... if(i < arr.length - 1)
... return arr[i] * foo(arr, i + 1);
... return arr[i];}

console.log(foo(array,0));
```

Comment: Si bueno, @Riven, cuando editaba mi respuesta no vi que estuviera lista la primera y creéme que me hubiera servido de ejmplo para recordar esta regla de no proveer soluciones sin ejemplo previo del OP. Sin embargo, me quitaron dos puntos? quien más votó así. Ni siquiera es copia de la primera.... Injusto x2

Comment: En el sitio quitan 2 puntos por cada voto negativo, por lo que nadie mas voto negativo, aunque bueno, quizas siendo nuevo usuario no debi haberte puesto el negativo :/, si editas tu respuesta creo que puedo quitartelo, si no estoy mal, asi funciona el sitio, ya que si no la editas no me deja editar el voto, y pues, con eso te devolverian los 2 pt.

Comment: Listo, solo consdieraciones de seudocódigo para un op que aún no comprende recursividad. Es así?

Comment: De hecho tu respuesta estaba bastante bien anteriormente, con codigo y todo, ya te quite el voto negativo, pero creo que deberias dejarla como antes, quizas lo unico que yo le añadiria es una explicación de las llamadas, de esta manera el OP va a entender de mejor forma. Aunque esto ultimo va a tu parecer amigo, la verdad bastante bien tu respuesta,

Comment: Gracias @Riven por la reversión y edición, al menos no quedé con menos puntos.